# uninstall npm but 'cmd-shim' missing

Tags: npm

I am trying to uninstall npm :

```
sudo npm uninstall npm
```

but I am getting this error :

> npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-16-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "uninstall"
>    "npm" npm ERR! node v5.6.0 npm ERR!
>   npm  v3.6.0 npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>
> npm ERR! Cannot find module 'cmd-shim' npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you need
>   help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/techvalley/dev/workspace/npm-debug.log

Anybody knows why?
Thank you.

Comment: I think trying to uninstall NPM _using_ NPM is probably going to give you problems.

Comment: I have tried every commands I could find , but none did work. NPM is still on my computer...

Comment: Ah, I take it back, that is how the docs say to uninstall it. There's some more info in there that might help you though, under "More Severe Uninstalling" - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall node, it should remove npm.